# How to do Aadhar Authentication and fetch KYC details using API

Tags: api, authentication, one-time-password, demographics, aadhaar

We are developing a mobile app for our health care client. To keep the patient signup/registration process quick we will use Aadhar APIs. So that patient will enter his/her Aadhar number after that will receive OTP and submit it to Aadhar authentication API and once authentication is successful we will fetch demographic details of a patient like a Name, Address, DOB, etc. using KYC API.

I have already gone through the

AADHAR OTP Request API - https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/aadhaar_otp_request_api_2_5.pdf

AADHAR Auth API -
https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/aadhaar_authentication_api_2_5.pdf

Aadhaar e-KYC API -
http://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/aadhaar_ekyc_api_2_5.pdf

But these official documents only explain the endpoints, communication protocol, and request/response formats. It does not offers clear help for the software developers in order to use and integrate it into the website/mobile app.

Is there any other way via which we can do the customer onboarding process quickly and smoothly?

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mahendra